# How to change coordinate system inside a tikz path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

So recently I started getting my feet wet with drawing 3D drawings.
I'm trying to draw a 3d drawing with the tikz 3d library. But I'm facing some problems.

mainly commands like `circle`, `arc`, and `rectangle` don't seem to work in the third dimension, which makes sense, since they work in the plane. To work around this, the pgf manual specifies that you can simply select a plane, and where on the normal vector you want to be, and then draw on that plane. In the pgfmanual (3.1.6a section 40.3) they do this in the `scope` environment. The problem with this is that you cannot then draw outside the plane.

So I was wondering if there was some way to select a plane for commands like `circle`, `arc`, and `rectangle` without entering a scope. The idea is that I would like to integrate these commands into a larger draw or fill command, for example by changing the coordinate system in the middle of a path:
`\draw (0,0,0) -- ++(1,0,0) arc [yzplane at x=1, start angle=0, end angle = 180, radius=1] -- cycle;`

My concrete problem is shown below. I have placed a circle on the `yz` plane, and I want that to be the circle of a cone. I can then draw lines to the edges of this circle, but I cannot figure out how to shade it in.

Below you see my attempt at getting this circle shaded, but as you can see, it's placing the `arc` in the `xy` plane instead of the `yz` plane.

Is there a way to get around this using the `3d` tikzlibrary? Is there away to get around it using `tikz-3dplot`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage\[T1\]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\[z={(90:10mm)},x={(190:10mm)},y ={(-45:10mm)}\]

        \def\circleplace{-2};
        \def\circleSize{0.4}
        \coordinate(coneTop) at (0,0,0);

        \begin{scope}\[canvas is yz plane at x=\circleplace\]
            \draw (0,0) circle (\circleSize);
            \draw\[thick, dashed\] (135:\circleSize) arc \[start angle = 135, end angle = 315, radius=\circleSize\]; 
        \end{scope}

        \filldraw\[fill = red, fill opacity = 0.2\] (coneTop) -- (\circleplace,{\circleSize*cos(135)},{\circleSize*sin(135)}) arc \[start angle= 135, delta angle =  180, radius = 0.4\] -- cycle;
        \draw\[dashed\] (\circleplace,{\circleSize*cos(135)},{\circleSize*sin(135)}) arc \[start angle= 135, delta angle = -180, radius = 0.4\];

        \draw (coneTop) -- (\circleplace,{\circleSize*cos(135)},{\circleSize*sin(135)});
        \draw (coneTop) -- (\circleplace,{\circleSize*cos(315)},{\circleSize*sin(315)});

        \draw (1,0,0) -- ++(1,0,0) node\[anchor=south\]{$x$};
        \draw (1,0,0) -- ++(0,1,0) node\[anchor=south\]{$y$};
        \draw (1,0,0) -- ++(0,0,1) node\[anchor=south\]{$z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done by using symbolic coordinates. You can access them from within the scope that brings you in the plane.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(90:10mm)},x={(190:10mm)},y ={(-45:10mm)},line cap=round,line join=round]
 \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O) (1,0,0) coordinate (X);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
  \draw (O) -- (X) arc[start angle=0, end angle = 180, radius=1] -- cycle;
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that you can change the coordinate systems in a path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(90:10mm)},x={(190:10mm)},y ={(-45:10mm)},line cap=round,line join=round]
 \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(1,0,0) [canvas is yz plane at x=0]
 arc[start angle=0, end angle = 180, radius=1] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are situations in which you do not want to have the projections that come with the `3d` library's styles, in which case you can set up your own `[yzplane]` that can gets injected in a path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(90:10mm)},x={(190:10mm)},y ={(-45:10mm)},line cap=round,line join=round]
 \path[overlay] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) (1,0,0) coordinate (ex)
  (0,1,0) coordinate (ey) (0,0,1) coordinate (ez);
 \tikzset{yz plane/.style={x={(ey)},y={(ez)}}} 
 \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(1,0,0) [yz plane]
 arc[start angle=0, end angle = 180, radius=1] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This means that when using `tikz-3dplot` you can insert `[tdplot_main_coords]` or `[tdplot_screen_coords]`, say, within a path to switch to a new coordinate system in the middle of a path.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful ;-) Now I like 3d again 8-) If I want to draw more in 3d space after `[yz plane]` should I simply define `\tikzset{xyz space/.style={x={(ex)},y={(ey)},z={(ez)}}}` and call `[xyz space]` before running  the next draw command?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Yes, precisely. Please note that `tikz-3dplot` has `tdplot_rotated_coords` for this, but it is sometimes more convenient to define `(ex)` and so on by hand. That is, if you know how to install orthographic projections, you do not necessarily need `tikz-3dplot`, you can also use the `tpp` library to install a view (without really using the perspective features).

Comment: Hello again. It seems like the style `[yz plane]` does not work with the `rectangle` command while `[canvas is yz plane at x=\x]` does seem to work. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Yes. `yz plane` only transforms a coordinate system but not a projection. You can find `\pgftransformtriangle` in the `3d` library which accomplishes the latter.